# Problem when importing Lucid in Next.js project with Typescript

Tags: library, lucid

I am getting the following error when trying to import `lucid-cardano` in a Next.js Typescript project:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property Headers of #<Object> which has only a getter
    at file:/node_modules/lucid-cardano/esm/src/core/core.js:12:20 {
  page: '/'
}
```

I also found this recent issue submitted to Lucid: https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid/issues/106

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in `lucid-cardano` library. It was fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/spacebudz/lucid/pull/108). I was able to re-test and my Next.js project is working as expected.